# Can't show mat-error message from custom Validator involving multiple form fields

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

This question is specifically about the `mat-error` component of AngularMaterial.

I have an Angular reactive form with password and password confirmation fields. To compare them, I'm using the custom validator below:

```
export function createConfirmPasswordValidator(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const value = control.value;
    if (!value) {
      return null;
    }

    return control.value.password === control.value.passwordConfirmation
      ? null
      : { passwordNoMatch: true };
  };
}
```

The validator itself is working - the related button is disabled when `!form.valid`, and testing with a valid email and password, but non-matching confirmation keeps the button disabled.

The `FormGroup`:

```
 this.form = new FormGroup(
      {
        email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
        password: new FormControl('', [
          Validators.required,
          createPasswordStrengthValidator(),
          Validators.minLength(8),
        ]),
        passwordConfirmation: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      },
      {
        validators: createConfirmPasswordValidator(),
      },
    );
```

And the HTML element:

```
...
      <mat-error i18n test-id="error-confirmation-nomatch" *ngIf="form.errors?.['passwordNoMatch']">
        Passwords must match
      </mat-error>
...
```

If I replace this `mat-error` for a `p` tag, I can see the message. If I print the `form.errors` in a `p` tag, as below, I can see that the error is set:

```
<p>{{form.errors | json}}</p>
```

Output:

```
{ "passwordNoMatch": true }
```

Something to note, though, is that this error appears in the `p` tag above as soon as I type anything in the `password` field and disappears when a matching password is put in the confirmation field.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: @YongShun Yes! Thank you!!!